# Corda 5 Exception

Tags: java, corda, corda-flow

*I get this error when calling flow management API in corda 5 `/flow/{{short_hash}}`.*

```html
{
  "flowStatusResponses": [
    {
      "holdingIdentityShortHash": "4558C1BAA9F2",
      "clientRequestId": "test-flow-1",
      "flowId": "c05a1690-fa8e-46b4-a026-825205f086b5",
      "flowStatus": "FAILED",
      "flowResult": null,
      "flowError": {
        "type": "FLOW_FAILED",
        "message": "Execution failed with \"Failed to create the sandbox: Failed to resolve bundles: javax.activation-api [512], jaxb-api [513], com.opencsv [515]\" after 5 retry attempts."
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-09-28T15:33:14.410Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

*Does anyone have any idea what's happening here? I assumed it should work without having to have to add any additional dependendies.*

Comment: Was the Java version upgraded recently?

Comment: No. I'm still on Java 11 as it's stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that your dependencies libraries require sandbox security policy adjustments. You can find more explanations here:

https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/5.0/deploying-operating/config/security-policies.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it by re-installing the corda cli with java 11, same as the version used in the project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).